# ASP.NET MVC 3 ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

OK, I have a problem where the `ModelState` errors are not mapping to the correct properties.

Let me see if I can explain this.

I have a ViewModel like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

In my view, I have a model that has a collection of this type which I have an `EditorTemplate` for. So it generates `MyViewModels[0].Prop1`, `MyViewModels[1].Prop1`, etc.

Problem is, when I set the error on the `ModelState` in my service layer via an interface I have made called `IValidationDictionary` which has a wrapper around model state, it does not attach the error to the correct row in the view, rather to the end of the model as `Prop1`.

## EDIT

Here is the ModelStateWrapper (VB - Sorry!)

```
Public Class ModelStateWrapper
    Implements IValidationDictionary

#Region "Private Members/Properties"

    Private modelState As ModelStateDictionary

    Public ReadOnly Property IsValid As Boolean Implements IValidationDictionary.IsValid
        Get
            Return modelState.IsValid
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region

#Region "Constructor(s)"

    Public Sub New(modelState As ModelStateDictionary)
        Me.modelState = modelState

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Methods"

    Public Sub AddError(key As String, message As String) Implements IValidationDictionary.AddError
        modelState.AddModelError(key, message)

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: Without seeing any of the code that is wrapping around the model state, how do you expect anyone to be able to answer why it's not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you *may* be using *Dependency Injection* and injecting the `ModelStateDictionary` into your `ModelStateWrapper` class, which is again injected into your *Service Layer*?

I can **only guess** whatever is getting injected is **not using** the [`Controller` class ModelState property (ModelStateDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate.aspx) of your current HTTP request.

Are you by any chance initializing **a new instance** of `ModelStateDictionary` and passing it into your `ModelStateWrapper`?
If you are using **Dependency Injection**, please show me your Injection configuration so I can give you a better answer.